# Vertical subfigures with captions on left

Tags: floats, subfloats, floatrow

This is what I want

[image]

I've tried a million things from floatrow package, subfloat, sidecap, etc. but nothing seems to work. This shouldn't be that hard to achieve I feel like but I'm all out of ideas.

Please help

edit: Current working example

```
\usepackage{floatrow}


\begin{figure}[htp]
%\centerline{
  %\ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[15mm]
      {\includegraphics[scale=.4]{zeta_zeropoint_05_A}}%
      {\caption{blah\\}}
   \end{subfloatrow}
  \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[15mm]
      {\includegraphics[scale=.4]{zeta_zeropoint_05_B}}%
      {\caption{blah}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[15mm]
      {\includegraphics[scale=.4]{zeta_zeropoint_05_C}}%
      {\caption{blah\\}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}
    %}
  {\caption{Fitting for subsample 1}}
  %}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,floatrow,graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{%
  font=footnotesize,labelformat=brace,labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Subcaption a)}}%
        {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
   \end{subfloatrow}

   \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Subcaption b)}}%
        {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}
      \fcapside[\FBwidth]
        {\caption{Subcaption c)}}%
        {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}}
  {\caption{Fitting for subsample 1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This was a great place to start for me, thank you so very much!

Comment: I'm still working to adjust this to center the captions with the center of the figures (vertically), kinda doing it manually. If you can help with that, that would be awesome!

Comment: Also, for me, this seems to work better without the \ffigbox{} wrapper, I don't know why that is.

Comment: Does `\floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesideposition={left,center},capbesidewidth=4cm}` do what you want?

Comment: Where is that line supposed to be? I didn't add any of the preamble type stuff above \begin{figure} really except to load the floatrow package. Is there a way to incorporate those corrections into the main figure code?

Comment: What do you mean by dropping `\ffigbox`?  Can you edit your question to provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at the code I provided above; replace the `\floatsetup...` from the answer with the one from my comment.

Comment: I edited the main post now. I'm trying to avoid the preamble stuff if possible because I want to retain the default formatting for the captions and stuff that matches with normal figures without all this floatrow stuff

Answer (score 0):

A concrete example with some minor variations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain,capposition = beside, capbesideposition={left, top},capbesidesep=quad, capbesidewidth =5cm, captionskip=20pt, rowpostcode=captionskip}
  \captionsetup[subfloatrow]{format=hang, labelfont=up, textfont=up}
  \captionsetup{labelfont=sc, textfont = it}
  \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\caption{ Le Déjeuner en fourrure (1936)\\(The fur cup)}}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{dejeuner.jpeg}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cahier.jpeg}}
      {\caption{ Le Cahier d’une écolière (1930)\\ (A schoolgirl’s notebook)}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]
      \fcapside{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{traccia-table.jpeg}}
      { \caption{ Traccia-table (1939)}}
    \end{subfloatrow}\\
    }{\caption{Three works by Méret Oppenheim.}
    \label{fig:label}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]